# Finding integer solutions to $\left[\sqrt{2}m\right] = \left[(2+\sqrt{2})n\right]$

Tags: number-theory

> Find the integer solutions of the equation $$\left[\sqrt{2}m\right] = \left[(2+\sqrt{2})n\right].$$(Note: $[x]$ denotes the greatest integer not exceeding $x$.)

I used Beatty's Theorem and found that since $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+\dfrac{1}{2+\sqrt{2}} = 1$, there are no positive integer solutions. How do we prove there are no negative integer solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** For all irrational numbers $\alpha>0$ and for all positive integers $n$, $\lfloor -\alpha n\rfloor=-1-\lfloor \alpha n\rfloor$.